# Sass function using color operations

Tags: css, function, sass

I'm trying to build a function to automate hover state operations. So gar I have this

```
$switch-element-hover:         20% !default;
$switch-element-operation:    "lighten" !default;


@function generate-hover-state($color) {   @return
#{$switch-element-operation}($color, $switch-element-hover); }
```

Then I try to use it like this:

```
&:hover {
  background-color: generate-hover-state($background);
}
```

Now I managed to compile it but the output looks weird:

```
background-color: lighten#626262, 20%;
```

Also I have tried using unquote as suggested by the tool but it doesn't seem to work.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it.

The answer laid in the @call method:
http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#call-instance_method

```
// Hover state function
@function generate-hover-state($color) {
  @return call($switch-element-operation, $color, $switch-element-hover);
}
```